# lstat doesn't detect symbolic link

Tags: c

I'm trying to check if a file is a symbolic link, my test doesn't seem to work. How can I check for symbolic links?

```
if (lstat(file->full_path, &file_info) == 0)
    printf((file_info.st_mode & S_IFDIR)  ? "l" : "");
else
    printf((S_ISDIR(file_info.st_mode))  ? "d" : "-");
```

Answer (score 1):

if S_ISLNK is defined:

```
S_ISLNK(file_info.st_mode)
```

Otherwise

```
if ((file_info.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFLNK)
```

So in your example:

```
if (lstat(file->full_path, &file_info) == 0)
   printf(((file_info.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFLNK)  ? "l" : "");
else
   printf("Could not get file stat info\n");
```

Note that if lstat doesnt return 0, it wont have any valid info in the file_info structure.